# How do I create an object in MyBatis (Spring) mapper using select on a table (Spring)?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, mybatis

I am new to MyBatis and Spring. I have two SQL tables, let's say a list of Universities and a list of Students.

```
UNIVERSITY table has id, name, listOfStudents

STUDENTS table has name_ofStudent, GPA, age, major, id, universityId
```

I have University.java, Student.java, UniversityManager.java, StudentManager.java (both with crud operations in their manager) (read's parameter is an int id).

If this is my UniversityMapper.xml (below) how do I "SELECT" (by ID) a University? I know how the basic select works but my main question is once I select get by id the name of the university how do I also so get the list of students belonging to that students?

I want to know how to select using mybatis the list of students that match the universityID and create a student object and make it part of the university object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="java.University">
  <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="java.University">
    <id column="ID" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="id" />
    <result column="NAME" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
  </resultMap>
  <insert id="createUniversity" parameterType="java.University">
    insert into DATABASE.University(ID, NAME)
    values (#{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
        </insert>

   <select id="getUniversity" parameterType="int" resultMap="java.University">

(This is where I need help)

</select>

   <update id="updateUniversity" parameterType="java.University">
    update DATABASE.University
    set ID= #{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      NAME= #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
  </update>
  <delete id="deleteUniversity" parameterType="java.University">
    delete from DATABASE.University
    where ID= #{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
  </delete>
</mapper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all written in the documentation in the part where they mention the [Advanced ResultMap](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps)s.

If your University class is something like this:

```
public class University{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Student> students;
    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

And your Student class is like:

```
public class Student{
    private String name_ofStudent;
    private Double GPA;
    private Integer age;
    private String major;
    private Long id;
    private Long universityId;
    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

You can have  query that gets the University and its Students as follows:

```
<select parameterType="Long" resultMap="UniversityResultMap">
    SELECT U.uni_id, U.uni_name, S.name_ofStudent, S.gpa, S.age, S.major, S.stu_id, S.stu_uni_id
    FROM UNIVERSITY U
    JOIN STUDENT S ON U.ID = S.UNIVERSITYID
    WHERE U.ID = #{id}
</select>
```

Then you can map the results as:

```
<resultMap id="StudentResultMap" resultMap="java.Student">
    <result column="NAME_OFSTUDENT" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name_ofStudent" />
    <result column="GPA" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="GPA" />
    <result column="AGE" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="age" />
    <result column="MAJOR" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="major" />
    <result column="STU_ID" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="id" />
    <result column="STU_UNI_ID" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="universityId" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="UniversityResultMap" parameterType="Long" resultMap="java.University">
    <id column="UNI_ID" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="id" />
    <result column="NAME" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
    <collection  property="students" ofType="java.Student" resultMap="StudentResultMap"/>
</resultMap>
```

If you have a different abstraction in mind about the classes, let us know.

Comment: Thanks alot! This helped! Up and running!

Comment: @SamiFekadu: since you are still using Stack Overflow, would you accept this answer? "Accepting" an answer means to mark it as correct and helpful. To do this, click the tick mark to the left of the answer so it turns green. This is how we thank people on Stack Overflow for their time and effort. Thanks!